# Jquery mobile autocomplete Select item

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

having issue's selecting an item from the list, it shows but nothing happens when i click, ive clearly not set an option, so when an item is clicked from the list, i want to call a click event, anyone point me in the right direction? (missing code/)

```
<script>
         $(function () {
             $("#autocomplete").on("listviewbeforefilter", function (e, data) {
                 var $ul = $(this),
                     $input = $(data.input),
                     value = $input.val(),
                     html = "";
                 $ul.html("");
                 if (value && value.length > 2) {
                     console.log($input.val());
                     $ul.html("<li><div class='ui-loader'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-loading'></span></div></li>");
                     $ul.listview("refresh");
                     console.log($input.val());
                     $.ajax({
                         url: "@Url.Action("ClientSearch","Schedule")",
                         dataType: "json",
                         type:"GET",
                         data: {
                             term: $input.val()
                         }
                     })
                         .then(function (response) {
                             $.each(response, function (i, val) {
                                 html += "<li><a href>" + val.FullName + "</a></li>";
                             });
                             $ul.html(html);
                             $ul.listview("refresh");
                             $ul.trigger("updatelayout");
                         });
                 }
             });
         });

     </script>
```

Comment: instead of `$(function () {})` try `$(document).on('pageshow',function(){ // your code });`

Comment: This is contained within a header and not a page, it all works im just trying to add a click\select event when an item is selected\clicked

Comment: `$(document).on('click', 'a', function () { alert('click') });` is this what you want?